# In C++ maximum std::streamsize is always equals to std::string max_size()?

Tags: c++

Does this example code result two equal values on all systems?

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()<< '\n';
    
    std::string example;
    std::cout << example.max_size() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I don't believe there is any requirement in the standard that would require them to be equal.

Comment: Why this is important? This values are so big that it is quite unusual to take them into a consideration.

Answer (score 2):

As specified at [C++11 Draft 27.5.2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf), it is an implementation defined type, so it's limits are not always equal across different platforms, compilers etc.

> *typedef implementation-defined streamsize;*
>
> The type streamsize is a synonym for one of the signed basic integral types. It is used to represent
> the number of characters transferred in an I/O operation, or the size of I/O buffers.300

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not guaranteed neither in theory, nor in practice. E.g. on my machine it prints:

```
9223372036854775807
4611686018427387903
```

For the record, it's a 64-bit GCC 10.2.0 by MSYS2 on Windows.